# Centos7 installation issue using pyenv

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, pyenv

Good day, I encountered an error when installing Python version 3.11.0 using "pyenv install 3.11.0"

and I already installed openssl-devel trying everything from Google to fix this issue. Is there in here
encounter this issue and fix it?

I tried to install "pyenv 3.9.0" and it's successful with no issue.

Thank you in advance

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.11.0/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 100, in <module>
    import _ssl             # If we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python SSL extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (CentOS Linux 7 using python-build 2.3.18)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20230601095845.30587
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20230601095845.30587.log

Last 10 log lines:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20230601095845.30587/Python-3.11.0 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \


Try to uninstall and install OpenSSL
```

Comment: Please consider editing your question and making it more concise. And also provide the codes/error codes in codeblocks